# HP ProCurve 5406zl does not accept direct attach cable with error "Not an HP Networking transceiver"

Tags: hp, switch, hp-procurve, 10gbethernet, sfp

I have an HP 5406zl switch running the latest firmware in the non-early release branch (K.15.14.0007, ROM K.15.30) and it is not accepting direct attach SFP+ cables in its SFP+ module. The module is a `J9538A` 8x 10GbE SFP+ module. The direct attach cables are Mellanox brand passive copper cables.

Is there a different firmware that permits the operation of unsupported cables, or is there a command a-la the Cisco command that enables unsupported SFP operation? That command, for reference, is:

```
service unsupported-transceiver
```

I would love to be able to get this switch working without having to shell out for HP direct attach cables at 4-5 times the price.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no equivalent on Procurve gear. If you baulk at HP prices, your best option is probably to look for a third-party supplier that will sell compatible parts with the SFP+'s coded as HP.

Answer (score 5):

With DAC cables, I usually let the switch dictate compatibility. Go with what is known-good on the switch and work from there.

The other part of this is your balking at prices. Part of working in this field is vendor management and establishing vendor relationships. There's almost *always* a better pricing option; especially with HP equipment.

Try some of the liquidators in the US or even eBay. Recall that HP switch gear has a lifetime warranty, so you are covered as long as you buy blessed HP SKUs.